# What regular Faerûn-wide events are there?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms

I'm wondering if there are any regular, realm-wide events (about every century or so) that would affect the Material Plane. Either nearly everybody knows it's happening, or just that strong magic-users would feel it.

I love the Great Modron March, but it's too long between events. Maybe a comet or celestial alignment? Something along those lines, though, would be nice.

Answers focusing on 5e lore are preferred, but I'm open to existing lore as well.

Thank you, in advance, for your time and knowledge.

Comment: There isn't that much deep setting material for 5E. The kinds of events you're looking for are going to involve a further look back in the history of the Realms than current materials cover. Restricting your question to 5E is going to drastically reduce, if not eliminate, the possibility of an answer.

Comment: Thank you, Naut. TJL, I was afraid of that, but it makes sense!

Comment: Are you asking about the Forgotten Realms in general, or Faerun in particular, or the entire Material Plane in very general terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks for events that would effect "the Material Plane" and the Prime Material is not only Toril and its crystalspace, it contains all the other D&D prime worlds. Yet, since it is tagged "Forgotten Realms" and has the title "Faerûn events", here are a two examples that might provide some inspiration:

- [Comet K'Thoutek](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Comet_K%27Thoutek): With a period of 237 years, it is believed that its sighting on Toril is associated the birth of powerful people, like Elminster or the Simbul (their birth years would actually [imply 277 years](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=17827) instead of 237). [Source: AD&D 2e Spelljammer product *[Realmspace](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17259/SJR2-Realmspace-2e)*, page 53.]
- [Dracorage](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Rage_of_Dragons): A periodic Realms-wide event that caused all the dragons to go mad and wreak havoc in a senseless rampage. It was associated with the appearance of the King-Killer Star. Its cycles kept on going for over 26 millennia, but events in 1373 DR seem to have stopped future ones from happening.

Comment: Awesome sauce! Comet K'thoutek will probably work splendidly! Where did you find them, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Eric, I have updated the answer with the source for Comet K'Thoutek. Dracorage is described in a number of products, with the major source being the 3.5e sourcebook Dragons of Faerûn.